# Export Json response to a file in Karate Framework

Tags: karate

I created a java util function, which gets Json response and writes to a text file.

Java Code:

```
 public void write(String str, String path) {
            File f = new File(path + "\\Log.txt");
            try {
                Files.write(str.toString().getBytes(), f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

However, when I looked on the text file, it is not is proper json format. Nodes are not within in Quotation marks.

Sample Response:

```
  {
    name=Abc, 
    id=123, 
    statusCode=200
    }
```

Can someone give a work around to convert it to proper json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got a reference to a Java `Map` not JSON.

Please read this, it should make it clear: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

So try to do something like this first. I'm guessing here because you haven't provided enough info:

```
* string json = response
* MyCode.write(json)
```

Comment: Thank you adding the Map has solved the problem

Comment: @GauravKhurana if possible can you please post the sample code snippet :)

Comment: https://github.com/gauravkhuraana/Karate_JuggerNaut  i have the code here.. let me know if you are looking for anything specific. What peter said above is that we dont get a json but a Java Map which are like key value pairs